# Dispatch action on a specific datetime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am currently writing a React application where I need to listen on the next calendar entry in my Redux state.

I am seeking advice on how to do this most effectively and correct.

My `calendar` state reducer consists of:

```
entries: [
    {
        title: "Event 1",
        start: "2016-09-26T08:00:00.000Z"
        end: "2016-09-26T09:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        title: "Event 2",
        start: "2016-09-26T10:00:00.000Z"
        end: "2016-09-26T11:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        title: "Event 3",
        start: "2016-09-26T13:00:00.000Z"
        end: "2016-09-26T14:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

When the next event (Event 1) is going to happen, I would like to dispatch an event, to handle the state of this calendar entry. The entries reducer can be updated any time, so I need to be able to push entries in earlier than the next entry.

I have Redux and Redux Saga on my disposal for handling this.

Currently I am working with a Redux Saga listener like:

```
export default function * watchCalendar() {
    while (true) {
        const entry = yield select((state) => state.calendar.entries[0]);
        if (entry) {
            const now = moment().startOf("minute");
            const start = moment(entry.start);
            if (now.isAfter(start)) {
                 put(CalendarActions.setActiveEntry(entry));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But not working as expected, as the `while` is exiting after first try. I need to make it keep listening for the state. The above is not really as effective as I would want.

Any advice, ideas or code examples is welcome.

**UPDATE 1, 2, 3, 4**

I am still hacking a bit, a bit closer:

```
export function * watchNextCalendarEntry() {
    while (true) { // eslint-disable-line no-constant-condition
        const next = yield select((state) => CalendarSelectors.getNextEntry(state.calendar));
        if (next) {
            const start = moment(next.start);
            const seconds = yield call(timeleft, start);

            yield call(delay, seconds * 1000);
            yield put(CalendarActions.setActiveCalendarEntry(next));
        }
    }
}

function * currentCalendarEntry(action) {
    try {
         while (true) { // eslint-disable-line no-constant-condition
            const entry = action.payload;
            const end = moment(entry.end);
            const seconds = yield call(timeleft, end);

            yield call(delay, seconds * 1000);
            yield put(CalendarActions.setInactiveCalendarEntry(entry));
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (yield cancelled()) {
            // e.g. do something
        }

    }
}

export function * watchCurrentCalendarEntry() {
    while (true) { // eslint-disable-line no-constant-condition
        const action = yield take(ActionTypes.SET_ACTIVE_CALENDAR_ENTRY);
        const watcher  = yield fork(currentCalendarEntry, action);

        yield take(ActionTypes.SET_INACTIVE_CALENDAR_ENTRY);
        yield cancel(watcher);
    }
}

function getTimeLeft(date) {
    return date.diff(moment().startOf("second"), "seconds");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
export default function* watchNextCalendarEntry() {
  takeLatest(SUBSCRIBE_CALENDAR_ENTRY, subscribeCalendarEntry);
}

function* subscribeCalendarEntry({ nextEntry }) {
  const timeLeft = moment(nextEntry.start).diff(moment());

  yield call(delay, timeLeft);

  yield put(CalendarActions.setActiveCalendarEntry(nextEntry));
}
```

You would need to dispatch `{ type: SUBSCRIBE_CALENDAR_ENTRY, nextEntry }` action on start of the app and when entry changes then calculate and pass in nextEntry to the action.

Comment: Good idea with subscribing to the next entry - so if another entry is coming in, we count to it. Just have to make sure the "next" entry is the next entry in time also.

Comment: Yes, so nextEntry passing in need to be the next entry. If that makes sense, you can calculate this in the saga, but will have to use `select` effect